# How to access Polymer functions from JS

Tags: polymer, interact.js

Sorry if this comes out a bit garbled, I'm not sure how to ask this question.

What I am trying to do is keep the DOM synced with a localStorage value, and am updating the localStorage value with an interact.js mouse event.

Currently, I am able to properly set the localStorage value, but am having problems updating the DOM.

My current build is within the Polymer framework, so I am having trouble selecting shadow DOM content.

The DOM tree looks like

```
PARENT-ELEMENT
  # SHADOW ROOT
    EL
    EL
    DIV
      CUSTOM ELEMENT
    EL
    EL
```

Here are some ways I have failed to solve the problem.  The Custom Element is in pure JS, since I am not sure how to properly wrap interact.js function in Polymer:

1. I tried directly accessing the PARENT-ELEMENT's shadow DOM from the Custom Element in pure JS.

```
  var shadowDOMNode = document.querySelector('PARENT-ELEMENT');
  var dom_object_1 = shadowDOMNode.querySelector('#dom_object_1');
  dom_object_1.innerHTML = localStorage.dom_object_1;
```

2. I tried selecting a helper updateDOM() function from the PARENT Polymer element and running it from the Custom Element's setter directly.

```
if (event.dy > 0) {
    this.$$('PARENT-ELEMENT').updateDOM();
}
```

Maybe I am taking the wrong approach entirely, but I haven't been able to find analogues for interact.js in using native Polymer functions.

I hope this question was clear enough...

Comment: For your first approach did you try `Polymer.dom(shadowDOMNode).querySelector('#dom_object_1')` or instead create a property in `parentElement`, populate that with `localstorage` and have an observer on that property.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I am not well acquainted with Polymer observers, I am unsure of how to properly set one up in this case.  Would it be something like

    `value: {`
        `type: String,`
        `value: localStorage.lsValue,`
        `observer: 'DOM_helper'`
    `},`

    `observers: [`
        `'DOM_helper()'`
    `],`

    `DOM_helper: function() {`
        `this.$$('#dom_object_1').innerHTML = localStorage.lsValue;`
    `}`

Comment: You won't be needing the second `observer` array and in the function that observer calls you will be getting `newVal` so no need tp call `localStorage`, if you can provide some code snippet(jsbin, codepen, etc) i can help you with that or if you want i can provide you with an example of Observer and 2-way `property-binding`

Comment: or as @nicholas suggested you can create a public method and then pass use that method to update data.

Comment: OK, I am trying to work out these suggestions.  Creating a public method in the `parent-element` and calling it from the `custom-element` is the abstraction that made most sense to me.  However, I am not sure how to call a function in `parent-element` from `custom-element`, and cross the JS / Polymer barrier.

I am pretty sure there is a way to call Polymer's declaratively wrapped functions from JS, but I don't understand how.

Comment: If your child element is not inside `dom-if` or `dom-repeat` in parentElement you can call it using `this.$.childElementId.method`

Comment: The `child-element` is in the template of the `parent-element`, so I need to call a parent function.  I am setting `localStorage` from the `child-element`.  

It would be nice to be able to update the DOM with a `parent-element` helper function from the `child-element` in pure JS, so then the 'DOM_update_helper' function could be called right after the setter.

Is this approach acceptable, or should I reconsider the architecture?

Comment: Also, am having trouble finding a Polymer 1.0 CDN to import into JS Bin.

Comment: Using the actual names of the elements and functions, I am getting a `Cannot read property shop of undefined` error with:  `this.$.shop-mix-console.updateMixConsoleDOM;`  Should I be assigning an ID to the parent element?

Comment: here is the link for CDN "https://polygit.org/components/

Comment: Only alpha-numeric ids can be read this way. In your case you can use `this.$$('#shop-mix-console').updateMixConsoleDOM`

Comment: Ah, yes I am trying to call `this.$$('#shop-mix-console').updateMixConsoleDOM` in a JavaScript, so `this.$$` cannot be accessed since it is a Polymer function.  I would need to call the JS implementation of it.

Comment: @a1626 Not true. Non-alphanumeric keys require bracket notation (standard JS). In this case: `this.$['shop-mix-console']`.

Comment: @tony19 you are correct, i forgot about that one.

Comment: @dentedm i thought you were calling it from polymer element ie both parent and child were polymer. Anyways you can getElementById or querySelector instead of this.$$ in js

Comment: With `this.$['shop-mix-console'].updateMixConsoleDOM;` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shop-mix-console' of undefined`.  The `child-element` is in the shadow DOM of the parent...

Comment: @a1626, I have tried wrapping interact.js into a Polymer element.  I apologize for the lack of clarity.  If anyone has time for a screen share, I would be exceedingly grateful.

Comment: the code posted by @nicholas is actually making a call from js rather than `poolymer` so that should help you

Comment: OK.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore the `interact.js` part of the problem and focus on Polymer, you could probably solve this without coupling the two.

To bind to a `localStorage` value with Polymer, use the [`<iron-localstorage>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-localstorage) element. In the following example, the `localStorage` value named `flavor_1_amount` is loaded and stored into a property named `_flavor1Amount`. If the value doesn't exist in `localStorage` or is empty, the `<iron-localstorage>` element fires an event (`iron-localstorage-load-empty`), which allows you to bind to a callback (e.g., to initialize it).

```
<iron-localstorage name="flavor_1_amount"
                   value="{{_flavor1Amount}}"
                   use-raw
                   on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="_initFlavor1Amount">
</iron-localstorage>
```

In the same element, you could provide an input for the user to update the `localStorage` value.

```
<paper-input label="Flavor Amount (mL)" value="{{_flavor1Amount}}"></paper-input>
```

And you can use [`<iron-localstorage>.reload()`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-localstorage#method-reload) to keep your data binding in sync, assuming it could be changed externally.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pbwWBZ?editors=1010) for a full demo. Check your `localStorage` from Chrome DevTools:

[image]

Comment: Tony, thanks for the assistance.  I think this thread got off track.  I understand how to update via the traditional Polymer way, but need a hybrid solution to update the shadow DOM in JS.  I am looking to increment a variable by observing the result of a mouse drag listener and updating the DOM with that value.

Comment: Would you recommend using a hidden button element that gets clicked by firing a JS function to update the DOM?

Comment: I am trying to build a range slider that only responds to relative positioning,  not absolute position. So swipe up 10 pixels increments value by 10, swipe down 15 pixels decrements by 15.  No hard resetting when a particular position is clicked in the range.

Comment: Hey Tony, thanks for helping me get back on track.  Was able to work out the problem with the help of you and Nicholas and this resource: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should use `this.set()` or any of the [array mutation methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#array-mutation) if it's an array in order for the ShadowDOM to be *notified properly.*

Since you want to perform this update from outside the element itself, imperatively, I'd suggest this:

- Expose a couple of methods from your element that you can use to add/remove/change property values from outside your element.
- These methods would internally use the proper channels to make the changes.

An example (you can call `addItem()` to add items from outside your element):

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
      <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    "use strict";

    Polymer({

      is: "x-example",
      properties: {
       data: {
          type: Array,
          value: [
            {name: "One"},
            {name: "Two"},
            {name: "Three"}
          ]
        }
      },
      
      // Exposed publicly, grab the element and use this method
      // to add your item
      addItem: function(item) {
        this.push("data", item);  
      }

    });
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<x-example id="x-example-elem"></x-example>

<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    // simply 'grab' the element and use the 
    // `addItem()` method you exposed publicly 
    // to add items to it.
    document.querySelector("#x-example-elem").addItem({name: "Four"});
  }, 2500);

</script>
```

**Important:** That being said, this is not the "Polymeric" way of doing stuff as this programming-style is imperative, in constrast with Polymer's style which is more declarative. The most Polymeric solution is to wrap your interact.js functionality in an element itself and use data-binding between your 2 elements to perform the changes.

Comment: @dantedm No problem but does it solve your question?

Comment: Still having trouble selecting a function from `shop-mix-console` (parent Polymer element) from `slide-block` (child element) written in JS, imported via Polymer in an attempt to keep the code modular.  Currently going back to watch some of Rob Dodson's Polycasts on data binding and observers.

Comment: I think my main problem is my inability to cross the Polymer-JS membrane in pure JS.  My architecture is a little wonky since I am relying on interact.js as an import, and haven't properly wrapped it inside of Polymer.

Comment: I am setting `localStorage` with a JS setter that fires when event.dy is changed, and am trying to update the DOM in Polymer by observing a change in `localStorage`.

Comment: Take my snippet above (it's a way to easily create Polymer elements in sandboxes (SO code snippet or JSFiddle) and produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me so I can have a look at what you are doing? Include only the essential parts of your elements.

Comment: OK.  Here is an attempt at the helper function... http://codepen.io/dantesmodern/pen/rLwGvj?editors=1000

Comment: your example doesn't work, your variable/prop names are completely wrong and that's not how `LocalStorage` works (you need `getItem()`, storage key/pairs are not properties of `LocalStorage` - furthermore you cannot bind a property to `LocalStorage` like that. I'm sorry but that's not an example I can help you with - You need to dive back into how Polymer works, at least the basics - Also the `$$` doesn't work like that and you shouldn't use it like that - Polymer sets the `innerHTML` by itself when you use it properly.

Comment: OK.  Was just fleshing out something quickly based on the suggestions I received and agree that I need a better grasp on the framework, which is why I was going back to watching the Polycast.

Comment: @dantedm That would be the ideal - even if I help you out here you'll get stuck again pretty soon, not to mention that if you'd be building everything the **wrong way**.

Comment: I have an `updateDOM` function that  works via `if (localStorage.recipeFlavor_1_amount) { this.$$('#flavor_1_amount').innerHTML = localStorage.recipeFlavor_1_amount + ' mL';}` and gets executed with a `ready` function.  I am struggling to call that function again repeatedly once the `localStorage` value changes.

Comment: To be blunt and straightforward - you're using Polymer the wrong way - you shouldn't be setting `innerHTML` yourself. Stop whatever you're doing and go back to the Polymer basics. Also read up again on how `LocalStorage` works - the saved key/value pairs are **NOT** properties of `localStorage`, they need to be fetched via the `getItem()` method.

Comment: Sure, I realized that my architecture was getting wonky, that's why I reached out for help.

Comment: I am calling innerHTML since I don't have the interact.js functions wrapped properly inside the Polymer framework.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look over my problem.

Comment: @dantdm you can just have your interact.js functions outside of your Polymer element and just call methods on the element like I illustrated in my answer - that's far better than what you currently do.

Comment: @dantedm No problem :)

Comment: That is one approach that I took, but was unable to call the updateDOM Polymer function during the JS setter in the interact.js script.

Comment: Anyways, I appreciate you taking the time to correct my course.  I'll have to approach the problem again more thoughtfully.

Comment: @dantedm You shouldn't need to be calling `updateDOM()` - if your element uses `this.set()` or any of the array mutation methods, `updateDOM()` is called automatically by Polymer

Comment: Yes, but I am unable to select the DOM element with JS, due to my lack of knowledge regarding the JS shadow DOM implementation.  I apologize for my bumbling.

Comment: Also, AFAIK dot notation allows one to access array keys in the Polymer framework.

Comment: only if it's used as a `path` - e.g `this.set(path, value);` -> `this.set("myArray.1", "Hello")` would set property `myArray` at index 1 to "Hello".

Comment: OK.  Somehow it works on retrieval for me with 'localStorage.customValue'

Comment: But you do seem to know it well, so I will defer to your judgement.

Comment: no you are right - I was referring to indices - my bad :)

Comment: Hey Nicholas, thanks for helping me get back on track.  Was able to work out the problem with the help of you and Tony and this resource: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events.

Comment: no problem mate - if @tony's answer helped you, mark it as accepted - I doubt mine really helped, maybe the comments

Comment: Will do.  Thanks again Nicholas!